# How should I interpret a weighted genetic risk score?

Tags: genetics, risk, gwas

I created a weighted Genetic Risk Score (GRS) by summing the product of the [SNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism)-dosages times their regression coefficients from the [GWAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome-wide_association_study) in which I found them. So:

```
GRS = sum(dosage1 * coefficient1 + dosage2 * coefficient2 + ...)
```

The regression coefficients were reported per standard deviation in the trait in the GWAS. Does one unit increase in the GRS represent a standard deviation increase in 'genetically raised' trait?

Also posted on [biology.stackexchange.com](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/81053).

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please provide more information. For instance: (1) What is GWAS? Link please. (2) Define `dosage`. (3) What are you regressing on what? Please provide the code. (4) What is the question behind the question? [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Best regards

Comment: @Jim 1. [gwas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome-wide_association_study), 2. Dosage is a minor allele count,range 0-2. 3. Something like `glm(CaseControl~SNP1)` for all SNPs. 4. Help me to interpret GRS(Genetic Risk Score).

Comment: 1. What is the outcome? (cancer vs no cancer or response vs resistance/no response, death / alive) 2. What is the design: case control (50 cases matched to 50 controls) or longitudinal? 3. What was the model used to identify traits? Logistic regression or t-test (additive risk model).? If it was outcome dependent sampling, the "risk" has no interpretation other than the risk of being in the sample as a case.